# Parse JSON result via j2me

Tags: web-services, json, blackberry, java-me

I am creating a mobile application using j2me, which interacts with a webservice.  The webservice responds with JSON data.
How do I parse it and get the individual values?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470406/how-to-parse-the-json-response-in-blackberry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sun has a technical article - [Using JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) in Java ME for Data Interchange](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javame/index-139356.html) - which will be helpful for you.