# differentiate same class name in two diffent jar files

Tags: java, json, blackberry, jar

I am developing blackberry application using BlackBerry JDE 5.0.X , in which i am using 
JSONOrg to parse json response now JSONOrg has few .java file which is using java.lang.Class
from rt.jar file.

so now the problem is BlackBerry JDE also has its version of java.lang.Class in net_rim_api.jar (which is a dependent jar file for BlackBerry) but i want to take a reference from rt.jar... so how can i differentiate a class which has a same name in two different .jar file ?

Please do help..

Comment: well u r right it is opposed to net_rim_api.jar so what should i use for JSON parsing in Blackberry ?

Comment: Is there some sort of incompatibility between the JSON library you're using and the JDE implementation of java.lang.Class, i.e., does the code fail to run on the Blackberry JDE?

Comment: ya there is in JSON library getField method of class java.lang.Class is used while in JDE implementation there is no getField method for java.lang.Class file

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470406/how-to-parse-the-json-response-in-blackberry-j2me

Comment: What classes I have used Json.org parser before with out any issues. Their classes are fully qualified so there shouldn't be any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use the [JSON ME](http://www.json.org/java/org.json.me.zip) library from JSON.org - it has a proven track record of working well on the BlackBerry platform, with none of the problems you mention.