# What is the recommended way for calling remote JSON objects from native blackberry apps?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, json, blackberry

IF I am to develop a native application on blackberry, what would be the recommended way to call remote JSON object? As I understand native blackberry apps is coded using Java, would it still be able to contact a remote JSON object from Ruby on Rails? Has there been any blackberry framework to ease this use case?

Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another post from stackoverflow that will help you get started.

[How to parse the JSON response in Blackberry/J2ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470406/how-to-parse-the-json-response-in-blackberry-j2me)

Answer (score 1):

The JSON is normalized. So If you generate some JSON and consume this JSON, it can be in different language. You just need use JSON parser in each langage.